# How to Update or Refresh the ViewModel Data and then the View. Using knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

i have one page on which there is tree view control on click of tree view node i am trying to change view model and then view but it is not updating view.

Code

```
 var emp = new EmpViewModel();

 $(document).ready(function () {

    var EmpViewModel = function () {

        var self = this;            
        self.EmpNo = ko.observable("0");
        self.EmpName = ko.observable("");
        self.Salary = ko.observable("");
        self.DeptName = ko.observable("");
        self.Designation = ko.observable("");
        var EmpData = {
            EmpNo: self.EmpNo,
            EmpName: self.EmpName,
            Salary: self.Salary,
            DeptName: self.DeptName,
            Designation: self.Designation
        };

        self.Employees = ko.observableArray([]);         


    ko.applyBindings(new EmpViewModel());
});


function OnTreeviewNodeSelect(e) {
         emp.EmpNo(e.EmpNo),
           emp.EmpName(e.EmpName),
           emp.Salary(e.Salary),
           emp.DeptName(e.DeptName),
           emp.Designation(e.Designation)

            ko.applyBindings(emp);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's useful to provide much more in the way of code and real examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your very first line will cause an error because `EmpViewModel()` is only defined inside your ready function, but you're trying to call it as if it were global. Thus `emp` will be undefined, and your assignments in `OnTreeviewNodeSelect()` will also cause errors.

Also, you're trying to call `ko.applyBindings` at least twice; this will cause a Knockout error.